# I need to fill an sg.input event via a keyboard app function that I have created in Pysimple gui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I' am currently working on a Gps of Rallye with Python and I'm using the module PysimpleGui.
My issue is the following I have a function where I can fill some rows (it's like a spreadsheet) and the type of event of the rows that I can fill is sg.Input.
But my interface has to be tactile. So I wrote a dedicated function to that, it's a keyboard app that return the number I'm entering in.
What I want to do is when I'm clicking on a input row my keyboard function would be called then I can enter a value in the keyboard and the value of the row become equal to the value that I've returned with my keyboard function.

My layout with the rows looks like this and the concerned rows are the one with key=(row, 2) and key=(row, 3) :

```
for row in range(0, 100):
    current_row = [
        sg.Text(row),
        sg.Text(size=(10, 1), pad=(0, 0), key=(row, 1)),
        sg.Input(size=(10, 1), pad=(0, 0), key=(row, 2)),
        sg.Input(size=(10, 1), pad=(0, 0), key=(row, 3)),
        sg.Text(size=(10, 1), pad=(0, 0), key=(row, 4)),
    ]
```

Here is my keyboard function that is already working well.
It's a basic keyboard with only digits :

```
def keyboard():
layout = [
    [sg.InputText(size=(14, 1), font=("Helvetica", 20), key='input'), sg.Button('Clear', size=(5, 1), font=("Helvetica", 20))],
    [sg.Button('1', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('2', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('3', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20))],
    [sg.Button('4', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('5', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('6', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20))],
    [sg.Button('7', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('8', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('9', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20))],
    [sg.Button('.', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('0', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20)),
    sg.Button('Enter', size=(5, 2), font=("Helvetica", 20))]
]

window = sg.Window('Keyboard', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:
        continue
    if event == 'Enter':
        return values['input']
    if event == 'Clear':
        window['input'].update('')
    else:
        window['input'].update(values['input'] + event)

window.close()
```

I've tried to call my keyboard function if event was (row, 2) or (row, 3) but it doesn't work.
And here is the part of my code where I'm filling the rows so I think it's where I need to implements the changes :

```
for row in range(0, 100):
    if row < 100 and values[(row, 2)] != '':
        window_settings[(row + 1, 1)].update(values[(row, 2)])
    if values[(row, 2)] != '' and values[(row, 3)] != '' and values[(row, 2)] != '0' and values[(row, 3)] != '0':
        dataframe.loc[row, 'Fin'] = float(values[(row, 2)])
        dataframe.loc[row, 'Vitesse'] = float(values[(row, 3)])
        window_settings[(row, 4)].update(get_time(dataframe, row))
```

Thanks to anyone that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example to demo how to fill a Input element by clicking the keypad buttons.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

pad = ["123", "456", "789", ".0↵"]
keys = ''.join(pad)

sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 16))

layout1 = [[sg.Input(size=10, key=(row, col)) for col in range(3)] for row in range(6)]
layout2 = [[sg.Button(key, size=(3, 1), expand_y=True) for key in row] for row in pad]

layout =  [[sg.Column(layout1, pad=(0, 0)), sg.Column(layout2, pad=(0, 0), expand_y=True)]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, margins=(3, 3), finalize=True)
for key in keys:
    window[key].block_focus()
window[(0, 0)].set_focus()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in keys[:-1]:
        element = window.find_element_with_focus()
        element.update(element.get()+event)
    elif event == keys[-1]:
        element = window.find_element_with_focus()
        element.get_next_focus().set_focus()

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: This might help me thanks !